# Generate random site links - ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I got no code to show this time as I'm actually lost on where to even start. In this application I have a *Quick Nav* in the left column, and in that I would like to be able to generate 5 random links to sections of the site. That way I could create a strongly typed partial view and execute it on each view to generate random links for the quick nav.

I hope this is making sense, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a sitemap populated where links can be fetched randomly? or do you really mean random links..

Comment: Well I'm wanting to (without having a SiteMap if possible) to be able to generate 5 random site links based on the controllers/view that are in the application. Like on one page have something like Home, About, Contact, Store, then another page have Store, Gallery, News and so on.

Comment: Can you just add a bunch of pages/urls to a table in a database and select 5 from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a sitemap and randomly select 5 links from it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx